# Path elements outside svg [d3-geo, topojson]

Tags: svg, topojson, d3-geo

I made a choropleth map for freecodecamp project.

```
https://codepen.io/prewol/pen/rNvxGZy
```

[the g elements start outside the svg parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq9K9.jpg)

```
.graphCont {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: beige;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgb(60, 80, 92);
  border-radius: 5px;  
}
```

It passed all of the tests but I can't center map (path or g elements) inside svg element. It looks like it have its origin outside the svg when inspected in the browser. The parent div is centered and the svg itself also, so why is the path elements outside it?